# Writing a program for editing .txt data - Python or Unix?

Tags: text-processing, python

I only have little experience in programming, and I'm currently working on improving my skills.
Basically, I need to write a program, that can do some specific processes to some data in a .txt file.

To start from scratch, I have a .txt file with data looking like this:

```
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//     x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//         x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//     x   x
```

I need to do some weird stuff to this data, in order to end up with a data set, that can be analyzed in the software I use. Each "//..."-line refers to the group of data above, until the next "//..."-line

Here's a line-up of what I want to do:

Shift the "//..."-line, so the group of data it refers to is below this line, and not above it:

```
//         x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//         x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//              x   x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Add a unique name to each group after //, without shifting remaining text on the line:

```
//Name 1  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//Name 2   x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//Name 3        x   x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Output this to a new file, without changing the original.
Then grab each name-line + line below, and output this to a File2:

```
//Name 1  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
//Name 2   x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
//Name 3        x   x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Change the structure, so the naming is like the following, and output this to File3:

```
>Name 1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>Name 2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>Name 3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

The above data is in a structure, I can actually analyse.

Now I know this is guite the task, and I am not asking you "how do I program this. I would just like to know, where you guys would start with such a project, and what language do you think fits the project best?

I managed to do a few things in unix, by getting help on this site. E.g. Giving unique names to each "//..." line, by the following unix code:

```
awk -F '' '/\/\//{n++ ; t=" Name "n ; sub("// {0,"length(t)-1"}","//"t)}{print}' File1.txt
```

Could you give me some hints for where to start?
Is the problem suitable as a Python project?
The original .txt data file contains a lot of data, so it is not possible to do the processing by hand. Also this project is meant as a way to get further into programming.

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like a python job to me. A general rule of thumb is: if your task requires only a "flat" and content-blind processing, core utilities (preferably gnu) are the way to go. This goes for string replacement, deletion, line-based processing, simple sorting, counting, filtration and so on... these tools allow you to very quickly write a one-liner to do what you want, with practice it doesn't even require much thinking.

On the other hand, if you need a complex job that needs to look around the file, imply a hierarchical (tree-like) structure, custom delimiters, and context-aware strings, then it's much easier to have the same structure available in your programming language. An extreme example are html/xml/json files, any files with nested braces and so on... if you have very powerful data structures available (python does), just write it in, process it in object-like fashion and read it back out. You can still do it in awk (or with a bit more effort in sed), but it's not worth it.

In your case, you will need to memorize position of the previous marker (or hold a long buffer) which gets a bit clumsy with line-processing software. In python, however, it's easy.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as file, open(sys.argv[2],'w') as file1, open(sys.argv[3],'w') as file2, open(sys.argv[4],'w') as file3:
    counter = 1
    current_buffer = []
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('//'):
            #we found a delimiter, flush the buffer
            #could use regular expressions, but for the sake of this example
            #this is enough
            prefix = '//Name {}'.format(counter)
            new_header = prefix+line[len(prefix):]
            file1.write(new_header)
            file2.write(new_header)
            for oldline in current_buffer:
                file1.write(oldline)
            if current_buffer: #only first line to file 2
                first_line = current_buffer[0]
                file2.write(first_line)
                #same here, could use regular expressions from "import re" but we don't have to
                rest_of_line = first_line.split(' ',1)[1]
                file3.write('//Name {} {}\n'.format(counter,rest_of_line.strip()))
            current_buffer=[]
            counter+=1
        else:
            current_buffer.append(line)

    #if the file is well-formatted, current_buffer should be empty now - otherwise, do special handling
```

Call it as `./test.py inputfile file1 file2 file3` and see if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer, @orion!
I'm having some trouble running the script, though.

I get the following error message:

`$ ./test.py test_file.txt file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
-bash: ./test.py: Permission denied`

I am on a mac, if that makes a difference.
I hope I'm doing it the right way. I have the file saved as test.py in the directory I am in in my terminal.
Then trying to call it with the command you gave me.

Comment: Right, I thought you knew... to run a script as an executable command, the file needs to have executable permissions. Either run `chmod +x test.py` and it'll work, or just call it explicitly with python: `python test.py ...`. Also, this was tested for python 3, python 2 may have some differences.

Comment: Okay, @orion, thank you! I have run the script, and I cannot believe how well it worked in the first run! :)
I guess this underlines why it is a huge advantage, to know some programming!
The only trouble I'm having is, that the insertion of the name shifts the rest of the line to the right.
This is a problem in my data, since the signs on the `"//Name…"` line refers to the column of letters just above (or beneath, after moving the name to the top) of the them.

Comment: Just replace `line[2:]` which means line, from 2th character forward, with `line[7:]`.

Comment: I see that is a simple way of doing it. However, the problem with using that method is that, as soon as x in the "Name x" is more than 1 digit, it doesn't fit anymore. :)

Comment: Just generate the name and measure its length. I fixed it.

Comment: There is an `awk` answer and a `sed` answer here and, from what I can tell, both represent significantly *less* effort than does your own answer. Perhaps the effort involved would be better described as proportional to one's familiarity with a tool?

Comment: @mikeserv Less code, but probably not less effort. I use awk and sed regularly, but for these kinds of jobs, legibility suffers, and python is still completely transparent what it does (but more verbose and therefore longer). I realize this is sort of a borderline case (as I said, parsing hierarchical data is way worse), but especially if a less experienced user will be using this code, having something that can be understood at a glance, and changed to adjust for needs, is much better. Of course all solutions are valid and the sed one is quite impressive, I would not have thought of using nl.

Comment: Ok, -good points all round. For someone without a working knowledge of regexp, yes, I'm willing to bet your answer is easier to understand. But a lot of people tend to forget that there's more to the standard toolset than std{in,out} and very often multiple goals can be accomplished in the same stream.

Comment: The above works perfectly! Thank you for your help!
Is it possible to make the counter start from 0, instead of 1?
So that I get Name 0, Name 1, Name 2...

Comment: Of course, you can see where it is initialized, just set `counter = 0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You should go with whatever makes you most comfortable. That said, you shouldn't avoid learning the use of a new tool either. I am pretty comfortable with `sed`, and it is my belief that `nl` is uniquely suited to this task, and so using a combination of those two tools I did:

```
<<\INFILE \
nl -bp'^//' -w1 -s'      ' |\
sed -ne ' s|^ *>|>|;//H;x;//x;t' -e 'G
        x;s|.*|### The following is written to: File1|p
        x;s|\([0-9]*\)\( *\)\( \)*//\2|//Name \1\3|pw File1
        x;s|1|2|p;x;s|\n\(\n.*\)*|&&|2;s|||2p;w File2' -e 'x;s|2|3|p
        x;s|//\([^ ]* [^ ]*\).*\n[^ ]*|>\1|pw File3'
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
//     x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//         x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
//     x   x
```

...which seems to do the trick.

When I say *`nl` is uniquely suited to this task* it is because, besides easily numbering blocks in order according to a pattern and injecting an arbitrary `--separator` string between the text on the numbered line and the line's number, `nl` also always indents lines it *doesn't number* to match the indent it adds to those it does.

This means that any line which does not get numbered as a match to the `^//` pattern now begins with a `<space>` instead. And so even if your actual text is much more complicated than the data in your examples, the `sed` is actually very easy to do. In fact, much of the above work is intended only to generate meaningful debug output as `sed` works. A fully functional statement could be as simple as:

```
nl -bp'^//' -w1 -s'      ' <infile |
sed -ne 's|^ *>|>|;//H;x;//x;t' -e 'G;h
         s|\([0-9]*\)\( *\)\( \)*//\2|//Name \1\3|w File1
         s|\n|&&|2;s|\n\n.*||;w File2
         s|//\([^ ]* [^ ]*\).*\n[^ ]*|>\1|w File3'
```

I am a little confused about your statement *without shifting remaining text on the line* because it seems to contradict your examples *(and the realm of possibility)*. I say this because:

```
//     x
```

...is obviously shifted *a little* to the right when it is transformed to:

```
//Name 1  x
```

...and in fact the *1* and the *x* occupy the same column in the two examples. I tried to meet that contradiction in the middle - it does not shift the text unless it must to avoid overwriting a non-`<space>` character while still inserting the `Name [num]` pair plus a single space.

Thus does not account for the discrepancy between...

```
//Name 3        x   x
```

...and...

```
//     x   x
```

...which I have disregarded as *(hopefully?)* a mistake in the example.

My pipeline prints everything to stdout, but the blocks following the lines beginning with `###` are appended each in turn to the indicated files as well. Here's what my pipeline prints:

```
### The following is written to: File1
//Name 1 x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
### The following is written to: File2
//Name 1 x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
### The following is written to: File3
>Name 1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
### The following is written to: File1
//Name 2   x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_3 abcdefghijklmnopqrst
>tex_4 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
### The following is written to: File2
//Name 2   x  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
### The following is written to: File3
>Name 2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
### The following is written to: File1
//Name 3 x   x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
>tex_2 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
### The following is written to: File2
//Name 3 x   x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
### The following is written to: File3
>Name 3 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
```

Comment: Good work! The idea to use `nl` to mark blocks and count is gorgeous! Everytime I have to refuse to use `sed` in case of even simple calculations but now, thanks of you, its obstacle is removed!

Comment: @Costas - it truly warms the heart to recognize the mark of another devoted `sed`der.

Comment: @Costas - come to think of it, another standard tool with which `sed` works very well is `dc`. A particularly interesting combination can be had when `dc` macros are programmed to read and compute line by line with the `?` read-input-line operator as `sed` feeds it from a pipe *(and vice-versa, for that matter)*. Add to that `dc`'s ability to execute arbitrary `system(...)` commands in-stream with the `!` operator, its huge, stackable arrays, `[string]` handling, ASCII num>char *(and vice-versa)* conversion... and the imaginative `sed`der could do some pretty powerful stuff between the two.

Comment: To my big regret I have never met `dc` in my life (just `bc` but it is not the same, is it?)

Comment: @Costas - `bc` is based on `dc`, and - though this changed a few years ago - `bc` used to be only a front-end to `dc`. It used to be that `bc` was basically just the lexer  because *(and perhaps rightfully so)* many were daunted by `dc`'s terse, stack-oriented syntax style. It was only fairly recently that `bc` came into its own as a fully separate entity in its own right, when the standard engine was generally adjudged *good enough* to do so. Still, I'm fairly sure that `dc` can outperform `bc` in most cases. Do `man dc` and have a look if you're curious.

Answer (score 2):

I can't agree that python is more acceptable in the case. There is no difficult line manipulation - just set variables and print various set of it. So its are usual bash' operations. So we need some calculations I prefer `awk` instead of `sed`(usual text manipulation programm).

```
awk -F '' '
          /\/\//{
                 n++
                 t="Name "n" "
                 sub("// {0,"length(t)"}","//"t)
                 print $0 "\n" l1 l2 > "File2"
                 print $0 "\n" l1 > "File3"
                 sub("[^ ]* ","<"t,l1)
                 print l1 > "data.file" 
                 l1=""
                 l2=""
                 next
                 }
          {
                 if (l1=="")
                     l1=$0
                 else l2=l2 "\n" $0
                 }' Input.txt
```

But everybody prefer that tool which he knows better.

P.S. Regarding the length of input string. If OP check your examples you can see that `«x» is above «e»`

```
//         x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

but after input `Name 1` `«x» is above «d»`

```
//Name 1  x
>tex_1 abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```

so in script shoul be `length(t)` not `lenght(t)-1`. Additionally if there in not enough space to input name script make necessary shift string's residue to right.